# Intersections with elliptic curves on a K3 surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, intersection-theory

This is a fairly simple question.

Suppose $E$ is an elliptic curve on a K3 surface $X$. Can we say that $E$ must intersect any curve $D\subset X$ of genus $g(D)\geq3$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact this is true for curves of genus at least 2.

For an elliptic curve $E$ in a $K3$ surface $X$, adjunction tells us that we have $E^2=0$. Then Riemann–Roch says that $h^0(X,E) \geq 2$; on the other hand, the ideal sheaf sequence for $E$ says that $h^0(X,E) \leq 2$. So in fact $h^0(X,E)=2$.

So the line bundle corresponding to $E$ has 2 linearly independent sections; since $E^2=0$ we conclude that the bundle is globally generated, so gives us a fibration $f:X \rightarrow \mathbf P^1$ with $E$ as one of the sections.

But then the only curves on $X$ which can be disjoint from $E$ are components of the fibres of $f$, which have genus 1 (if they are smooth fibres) or 0 (if they are components of reducible fibres).

Comment: Thanks Asal for your clean answer. I have two questions:
- why $E^2=0$ implies global generation?
- why the components of the reducible fibres are rational curves?

Comment: The bundle has 2 linearly independent sections: looking at their vanishing sets we get a curve $E'$ which is linearly equivalent to $E$ but distinct from it. But now $E \cdot E' = E \cdot E = 0$, so $E$ and $E'$ must actually be _disjoint_. This shows that the bundle is globally generated.

Comment: For the second q: well, one answer is that there is a classification of the possible reducible fibres of an elliptic fibration due to Kodaira (Annals of Math, 1950's). You don't need to know the details, but it shows that the components of a reducible fibre have to be rational. Basically, this comes down to computing how arithmetic genus behaves when we glue curves at points.